# Meteor - Unlock template for a certain period of time (by Date)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to show a Questionaire-Template for a period of time only. For from May the 5th until May the 9th.

I imagine something like a template helper that returns true if May the 5th has started and false if May the 9th has passed. But how can i efficiently update the momentary time value for the if-statement?

```
Template.registerHelper("questionaireUnlocked", function() {
  let now = new Date();
  let startDate;
  let endDate;
  if (now > startDate && now < endDate) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autorun to assign time to a reactive variable such as Session variable or ReactiveVar in the parent template.

```
Template.myParentTemplateName.created = function () {
  const template = this;
  template.autorun(function () {
     Meteor.setInterval(Session.set("newTime",new Date()), 6000);         
  });
}

Template.myParentTemplateName.helpers ({
  "questionaireUnlocked" : function () {
      const now = Session.get("newTime");
      .....
      if (now > startDate && now < endDate) {
          return true;
      }
   }
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - but when using the setInterval Method i get the following error in the console and the time is not updated: `Exception in setInterval callback: TypeError: func is not a function`

Comment: Got it: setInterval expects a function as the first value, wrawpping the Session.set in an anonymous function works: `Meteor.setInterval(()=>{Session.set(TIME_NOW, new Date())}, 6000);`